# Phonegap/Cordova app - Master app - different implementations

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, cordova-3

I am in the early stages of developing a Cordova app for our company that will be distributed on some of the major app stores. One of the core requirements are that this app must have a **"Master"** version, and essentially the same app will be distributed **(with their customizations i.e. ONLY cosmetic e.g. Logos, advertising etc.)** to each of our Clients interested.

So, essentially each client wants their own application. But, the code will be remain the same, and enhancements/bug fixes will be done on the "**Master**" app, and distributed to each client respectively. Is there a way of accomplishing this, without having to duplicate the app for each client. Naturally, they will also want their own app on the App stores, so

Our Company - Client A app.

Our Company - Client B app etc.

Is something like this possible? I hope this makes sense, I am a total beginner in mobile app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. You could use the master and update the Logos and so on dynamically via internet (some restrictions could apply specially for iOS).
2. You could create branches within your version control system.
3. You can have only one master version and several "config" files (one for each client) and depending on the client you could load the appropriate config file that instruct the app to load the custom assets, on that way you will only have to modify one line of code or only put the necessary config file in the appropriate path.

Be aware that this is not strictly a programming question so it could not fit inside SO.